# How to retrieve timestamp value to the viewer in MCV C# from an SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, timestamp

I have an issue with handling timestamps where the timestamp is save in the database.

I have to get the timestamp from the database to the viewer (User end as a hidden field). Timestamps are formatted like this: `0x00000000044C319D`.

Comment: what code are you using ?
a simple DateTime.Parse(db.timestampfield.ToString()) will do the trick.

Comment: And what value is 0x00000000044C319D meant to represent? How was the time originally recorded? If this is a SQL Server `timestamp` field, that's not really a timestamp in the normal sense - it's a row version.